# Complete list of dictionaries with date and zero values for the missing months in a range

Tags: python, python-3.x, date

I have a list of dictionaries like this:

```
[{'start_date': '2021-05', 'value': 1500.0},
 {'start_date': '2021-08', 'value': 6000.0},
 {'start_date': '2021-09', 'value': 3000.0},
 {'start_date': '2021-10', 'value': 2750.0},
 {'start_date': '2021-11', 'value': 19500.0}]
```

I want to add in the missing months (`start_date`) with `'value': 0`.

The output I want from the above dictionary would be:

```
[{'start_date': '2021-05', 'value': 1500.0},
 {'start_date': '2021-06', 'value': 0},
 {'start_date': '2021-07', 'value': 0},
 {'start_date': '2021-08', 'value': 6000.0},
 {'start_date': '2021-09', 'value': 3000.0},
 {'start_date': '2021-10', 'value': 2750.0},
 {'start_date': '2021-11', 'value': 19500.0}]
```

Now do I achieve this if my initial start date is 2021-05 and my end date is 2021-11?

I tried some ideas, but didn't get the correct format I need.

For clarification:

I tried creating a dict with the dates and value 0 and compared with the dict above, but it was in the wrong format and I don't know if it is the best way: (it gets an start date and end date, filling the missing ones, the initial date is a datetime, but my output is a str with month only)

```
end_date = job_start_date_end if job_start_date_end is not None else date.today()
if job_start_date_start:
    months_list = [
        dt.strptime('%2.2d-%2.2d' % (y, m), '%Y-%m').strftime('%Y-%m')
        for y in range(job_start_date_start.year, end_date.year + 1)
        for m in range(
            job_start_date_start.month if y == job_start_date_start.year else 1,
            end_date.month + 1 if y == end_date.year else 13
        )
    ]
    month_dict = {key: 0 for key in months_list}
else:
    month_dict = None
result = {**month_dict, **my_incomplete_dict}
```

This get what I want, but not in the format I need, the output is:

```
{'2021-05': 0, '2021-06': 0}
```

I don't know it it is useful, but my FINAL output my front-end needs (for a chart) is:

```
{
  "chartlabels": [
    "2020-05",
    "2021-06",
    "2021-07",
    "2021-08",
    "2021-09"
  ],
  "chartvalues": [
    1500,
    0,
    0,
    2750,
    19500
  ]
}
```

I already do that, but without the missing months.

Comment: I didn't understand what you are trying to do, nor what your question is (which may be because you didn't ask one).

Comment: Not sure if I've got this right but are you sure you want to use a list of dictionaries? Perhaps you should just be using a dictionary where, for every entry, the key is the date and the value is your"value" field.

Comment: `I tried some ideas, but didn't get the correctly format I need.` include some of the ideas you tried, will help us. include the "correctly format" you need also helps us a lot.

Comment: @Ben I receive the data this way, my final output is different (I edited the question for better clarification). In the end, what I want is my final output format with the missing months.  I already convert to my final output, but without the missing months. And my initial dict can have more than an element with the same year-month, I group_by then too (with the same initial format)

Comment: @mkrieger1 sorry, I edited the question for better clarification, with examples of what I want. My question is to fill the missing months with `'value': 0` in the same format of my initial list of dictionaries. But could be in my final output format too (with the missing values).

Comment: @chickitychinachinesechicken I edited with the code I tried and the output. My desired output could be in the format of my initial list of dictionaries or the final one, a dictionary with two lists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the complete answer which will give the data as I want, filling the missing months with value 0.
This will be used as a FastAPI response.

```
start_date = job_start_date_start if job_start_date_start is not None \
    else dt.strptime(result[0].get("start_date"), '%Y-%m')
end_date = job_start_date_end if job_start_date_end is not None else date.today()
months_list = [dt.strptime('%2.2d-%2.2d' % (y, m), '%Y-%m').strftime('%Y-%m')
                for y in range(start_date.year, end_date.year + 1)
                for m in range(start_date.month if y == start_date.year else 1,
                                end_date.month + 1 if y == end_date.year else 13)]
for yearmonth in months_list:
    if not any(d['start_date'] == f"{yearmonth}" for d in result):
        result.append({'start_date': f"{yearmonth}", "value": 0})
result = sorted(result, key=lambda d: d['start_date'])
# Change the format to my desired output
value_list = [result[value].get("value") for value in range(len(result))]
start_date_list = [result[value].get("start_date") for value in range(len(result))]
result_dict = {"chartvalues": value_list, "chartlabels": start_date_list}
return result_dict
```

This will get the following format:

```
{
  "chartlabels": [
    "2020-05",
    "2021-06",
    "2021-07",
    "2021-08",
    "2021-09"
  ],
  "chartvalues": [
    1500,
    0,
    0,
    2750,
    19500
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not completely sure what you are after, but this might be what you are looking for.

```
dictlist = [{'start_date': '2020-11', 'value': 1500.0}, {'start_date': '2021-08', 'value': 6000.0}, {'start_date': '2021-09', 'value': 3000.0}, {'start_date': '2021-10', 'value': 2750.0}, {'start_date': '2021-11', 'value': 19500.0}]

for year in list(set([d['start_date'].split('-')[0] for d in dictlist])):
    for month in range(1,13):
        monthstr = str(month).zfill(2)
        if not any(d['start_date'] == f"{year}-{monthstr}" for d in dictlist):
            dictlist.append({'start_date': f"{year}-{monthstr}", "value": 0})

newlist = sorted(dictlist, key=lambda d: d['start_date'])
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried a similar way (but in the wrong format, I will look if I can use your solution with mine), but the problem is, I don't want the whole year. I edit the question for better clarification.

Comment: I used your answer with the code I tried and it worked, thanks! I'm waiting the review to post the complete answer.